# Como realizo separador de miles y decimales en js dentro de un input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy realizando un sistema de facturación en js y angular pero no puedo colocar separador de miles y decimales en los inputs cuando saca el calculo y no me muestra la separación. Gracias por la ayuda
este es el código que uso

```
var formatNumber = {
        separador: ".", // separador para los miles
        sepDecimal: '.', // separador para los decimales
        formatear:function (num) {
        num +='';
        var splitStr = num.split('.');
        var splitLeft = splitStr[0];
        var splitRight = splitStr.length > 1 ? this.sepDecimal + splitStr[1] : '';
        var regx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (regx.test(splitLeft)) {
            splitLeft = splitLeft.replace(regx, '$1' + this.separador + '$2');
            }
        return this.simbol + splitLeft  +splitRight;
        },
        new:function(num, simbol){
            this.simbol = simbol ||'';
        return this.formatear(num);
        }
    }
```

```
var datarow = {
                                        id: $("#id_producto").val(), 
                                        codigo: $("#codigo").val(), 
                                        detalle: $("#producto").val(), 
                                        cantidad: $("#cantidad").val(), 
                                        precio_u_bs: precio_bolivar, 
                                        precio_u: precio, 
                                        descuento: desc,
                                        cal_des: resultado, 
                                        total_bs: total2, 
                                        total: total, 
                                        iva: $("#iva_producto").val(),
                                        incluye: $("#incluye").val()
                                    };
```

Comment: NO se entiende como esto esta relacionado con angular y el despliegue de la informacion. Puedes incluir el codigo o template que usas en angular para mostrar estos datos? Existen los filtros que se usan para realizar formato numerico https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira reescribi completamente tu funcion, esta te permite formatear el numero como lo deseas

```
function formatNumber(floatValue = 0, decimals = 0, multiplier = 1) {
    let floatMultiplied = floatValue * multiplier;
    let stringFloat = floatMultiplied + "";
    let arraySplitFloat = stringFloat.split(".");
    let decimalsValue = "0";
    if (arraySplitFloat.length > 1) {
        decimalsValue = arraySplitFloat[1].slice(0, decimals);
    }
    let integerValue = arraySplitFloat[0];
    let arrayFullStringValue = [integerValue, decimalsValue];
    let FullStringValue = arrayFullStringValue.join(".")
    let floatFullValue = parseFloat(FullStringValue) + "";
    let formatFloatFullValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { minimumFractionDigits: decimals }).format(floatFullValue);
    return formatFloatFullValue;

}
```

ejemplo:
no redondea, trunca los valores: el primer atributo es el numero que quieres formatear, el segundo es la cantidad de decimales que quieres, el tercero es un multiplicador si quieres agregar descuentos o algo asi.

```
formatNumber(10000.3122,2) //"10.000,31"
formatNumber(10000.3192,2) //"10.000,31"
formatNumber(10000) //"10.000"
formatNumber(10000,3) //"10.000,000"
formatTrazanetData(100012312310.31231212,5) // "100.012.312.310,31232"
formatTrazanetData(100012312313211.3434342,5) // "100.012.312.313.211,34000" <- se rompe con numeros muy gigantes
```

Comment: Gracias si me funciono y mucho :D